# Rename [tag:powerless] to [tag:unpowered]?

Tags: support, status-completed, retagging

'Powerless' seems like a misnomer. Can we rename it to 'unpowered'? That is at least a more typical term, although perhaps that's only in the US.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agreed. It would be good to get international input, as you suggest, but unless it's commonly used elsewhere, unpowered would certainly be preferred. I think glider pilots would take offense to being called powerless.

Comment: I'd agree -- a search for "unpowered" in the FARs returns multiple matches, while a search for "powerless" comes in empty-handed.

Answer (score 4):

I started the [powerless](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powerless) tag.

I had chosen it because [there is plenty of usage of the term](https://www.google.com/search?q=powerless%20flight&oq=powerless%20flight&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60.2650j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8).

Upon [researching more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unpowered_flight), I find that the term "unpowered flight" is [perhaps the more prevalent term](https://www.google.com/search?q=powerless%20flight&oq=powerless%20flight&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i60.2650j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=91&espv=210&q=unpowered%20flight).